# Community - sharing rule/Guest profile

Tags: community, sharing-rule, guest-user

On Friday I implemented the Guest record level security in production.  I added sharing rules.  Everything looked great.  This evening I needed to give the Guest user profile access to a custom field on a custom object.  I went into the Guest profile via Classic & added read access to the custom field.  The sharing rule immediately stopped working.  Also, when I go into the Guest profile via Community Builder, the rights that the Guest profile shows does not match what I see when I look at the Guest profile via Classic.  It seems that the sharing rules & Guest profile are out of sync somehow.  I have deleted the sharing rule & re-added it.  It is still not working.  Fortunately, I can still use the View All option.  I am hoping someone can shed light on what is happening & what I need to do to resolve the issue.

Comment: I am having a similar issue. Somehow the guest sharing rule is not working. The Sharing rule for the guest user is working fine on the sandbox but not working on the production. I gave View All permission to the guest user profile but can not figure out why the sharing rule is not working. I am using a custom object.

Comment: Waqar,

I was able to resolve my Guest user access problem.  I learned that records created/owned by Customer Community portal users are not viewable by the Guest users no matter what.  I worked around the problem by changing the ownership of records created by Customer Community users to internal Salesforce users.

It is a Salesforce limitation.  I received a notice that this problem is likely to be fixed in the Summer '21 release.